# Is there any possibility that pd.read_csv causes KeyError?

Tags: python, pandas, python-import

I keep getting 'KeyError' in my codes while analysing purchase data of a fashion brand. I'm guessing this is because the way I import csv file into python is wrong, but I don't know what to change. If you have any idea to fix it, please help me out!

I used to use pd.read_csv like

```
cst = pd.read_csv(rf'G:~~~~customer.csv', engine='python', encoding='cp932', dtype='unicode')
```

and I changed it into

```
cst = pd.read_csv(r'G:~~~~customer.csv', encoding='cp932', dtype={'ID': 'str})
```

Unfortunately, it never worked.

Just I want to prevent 'KeyError' from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has no dtype 'unicode' or 'str'. Please see https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html
You have to use dtype={'ID': 'object'}.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I tried what you suggested, but it didn't solve the problem......
I'm sorry,,,,

Answer (score 0):

It most likely because you might had a space between the keys

`col1 , col2 , col3`

Do change it to

`col1,col2,col3`

And make sure you

`cst = pd.read_csv('G:~~~~customer.csv', encoding='cp932')`

You need not have `dtype` the above would pretty much do work. else make sure you are using the correct `dtypes` from the [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dtypes)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
I tried what you suggested, but it didn't work......

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the dataset as it as so that it would be much useful for me to help you out?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: *dtype={'ID': 'str})* (I assume that missing closing apostrophe
is only in your question, not in your code).

Note that columns containing *string* values are in *Pandas* actually of *object* type.

So maybe you should change to *dtype={'ID': 'object'})*.

Another hint: Run *read_csv* (as a test) **without** *dtype* parameter.
Of course, the type of *ID* column will be this time other than expected,
but we want only to check whether *read_csv* is able to read this file at all.

If the same error occurs then the real cause is in some other place.

Check also that your input actually contains *ID* column (case sensitive).
*read_csv* may be raising this error if you refer to a non-existing column.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
As you said (I assume that missing closing apostrophe is only in your question, not in your code), I didn't miss apostrophe in my codes.
I changed str to object, but it didn't help.
Also, I tried to import the data without dtype, but it didn't work, either.
Lastly, I checked whether there really is ID column so many times using cst.columns and cst.keys(), and there sure is the ID column.
In this situation, do you think the real issue has nothing to do with pd.read_csv?

Comment: As the same error occurs **without** *dtype*, so the real cause is somewhere else.
Maybe your input file contains wrong content in some place.
To check this, divide your CSV file into parts (with column name row in each part) and try reading each part.
If any of these files can be read, and other not, take one of the "failed" files,
divide it into parts again and repeat the "partial reading".
Look also in the error description, maybe there is a hint concerning source line number. Then look **very thoroughly** at this line.

Comment: I did some search with Google and it looks that the real source
of your problem is *cp932*. Search the web for *pandas cp932*.
There is considerable number of web sites found, but unfortunately
(to me) in Japanese. Maybe you (as I suppose fluent in Japanese)
will be able to find some hint there.
Yet another hint: Convert your input file to UTF (I'm not sure
whether UTF-8 or UTF-16) and try to read with UTF encoding.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Indeed, deleting cp932 erased some errors (not all though).
I appreciste your advice!!!